# gzip Error : IOError: Not a gzipped file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, gzip, unzip

Im trying to unzip a .gz file with **gzip**. Everything works normally but for some .gz files, I got this Error message :

```
IOError: Not a gzipped file
```

This is the part of the code where I got the problem :

```
inF = gzip.GzipFile('C:/Users/MyUserName/ftvenFiles/file.gz', 'rb')
s = inF.read()
```

[image]

Help ?

Comment: The magic number is wrong -- those files are not gzip-compressed files. They're something else.

Comment: that's because they _aren't_ gz files. Have you tried opening them using another archiver like 7-zip, or even gzip itself?

Comment: I'm sure that those files are gzip-compressed files :(

Comment: @Data, are you on a Linux system? If so, please take one of those problematic files and run the `file` command on it. You will know for sure.